# What role does wValue play when interactive with "USB HID Red Visual Indicator" over USB?

Tags: c, libusb

```
unsigned char command = strcmp("on", argv[1]) == 0 ? 0x02 : 0x00;

// From Delcom documentation
unsigned char buffer[] = { 
    0x65, // 8 byte packet size
    0x0C, // Command type
    command, // DataLSB - Command parameter
    0xFF, // DataMSB - Command parameter
    0x00, // HID, first byte
    0x00, // HID, second byte
    0x00, // HID, third byte
    0x00  // HID, fourth byte
};

libusb_control_transfer (
    devh,
    0x21, // bmRequestType (host to device)
    0x09, // bRequest (set configuration)
    0x0635, // wValue (configuration value)
    0x000, // wIndex
    buffer, // Data / message
    sizeof(buffer), // wLength, Number of bytes to be sent
    0 // Timeout
);
```

I've bought a Delcom usb controlled light to hook up to our build server, but it turned out that the C example provided by Delcom no longer compiled on Ubuntu 14.04 so I figured that it would be a good opportunity to learn a bit C as well as a bit about how USB works.

After finding a Ruby implementation for a similar Delcom device I was able to control the gadget via my C program, but I would like to understand a bit more about how this works. The comment added to the code above is the result of hours of searching and reading, but there are still a lot of blanks to be filled in :-)

1. What role does wValue (0x0635) play? Is it a standardized configuration (argument to bRequest / SET_CONFIGURATION)?
2. wIndex (0x000) - Does it mean that data should be read from the start? Why would this be needed?
3. Why is there a need for an argument like wLength? '
4. Have I made any other incorrect assumptions in the comments?

Hope this question isn't too fuzzy for Stackoverflow :-)

The gadget in question:
http://www.delcomproducts.com/productdetails.asp?PartNumber=904402

Comment: By the way, I've uploaded the source code along with some of the resources I've used to Github: https://github.com/kimble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bmRequestType` is [more than the direction of the transfer](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb6.shtml).
It also indicates the type of request, here a Class request, and the recipient, here an interface.

When the recipient is an interface,  `wIndex` represents the interface number. An USB device can have multiple interfaces of different classes.

bRequest = 0x09 would mean SET_CONFIGURATION if it was a standard device request.

For a HID class request, `bRequest` = 0x09 means a SET_REPORT request (see [HID document, section 7.2](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/HID1_11.pdf) and the rest for more about HID reports).

How `wValue` is interpreted depends on the request. For a SET_REPORT request, it represent the report type in the high byte and the report ID in the low byte.

Report type is 0x01=Input, 0x02=Output, 0x03=Feature, 0x04-FF=Reserved. So in your case I guess it is specific to this device.

The data is the "report".

What reports contain can be defined in [standard HID usage tables](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage), like for standard keyboards, mice ... But it doesn't have to be.

For the length passed as argument, that is the same as in many C functions : the data argument is a `unsigned char *`, a pointer, the size can't be known if you don't pass it. You can use `sizeof` because your `buffer` is an array.

Comment: Thank you! This is by far the best answer I've ever gotten here!